# Align <img> tag flush with text in a table

Tags: html, css

I have a table, and in the second column I want to have some text with an icon immediately to its right, but the icon always wraps to the next line instead of appearing to the right of the text.

(I want

```
some text [icon]
```

in the second column, but I get

```
some text
[icon]
```

instead.)

Here is what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="tableDiv">
<div class="statusLine">
    <span class="statusHeader">A status</span>
    <span>
       <span class="status">some text</span>
       <img class="icon" width="16px" height="16px" src="img/completed.gif"></img>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="statusLine">
    <span class="statusHeader">B status</span>
    <span>
       <span class="status">other text</span>
       <img class="icon" width="16px" height="16px" src="img/ongoing.gif"></img>
   </span>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tableDiv{
    display:table;
}
.tableDiv .statusLine{
    display:table-row;
}
.tableDiv .statusLine span{
    display:table-cell;
    padding:5px;
    width: 200px;
} 
.icon {
   border-style: none;
}
```

It should be easy, but what am I missing?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1jbmbo5/4/)

Comment: What do you mean "goes to the next line"? I don't see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/e1jbmbo5/

Comment: Sorry, I meant to the next cell. I want the icon to be just at the right of the text whatever its length

Comment: No prob...did any of the answers address the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you're looking for: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1jbmbo5/3/)

Your `span` with the `status` class is inheriting the `table-cell` style from the previous CSS.  You need to explicitly declare a style for `.status` like so:

```
div.tableDiv div.statusLine span span.status { display: inline;}
```

This allows the `img` to butt up against the text in the `status` `span`, but keeps them both separate from the text "A status" or "B status".

(Colin almost had it right below, but missed a `span` in his CSS.)

Comment: OK. Thanks! My mistake was that I thought that in CSS A .B was every *direct* child of A with class B!

Answer (score 0):

Use img icon in span Tag like this :

```
<span class="status">Some Text<img class="icon" width="16px" height="16px" src="img/completed.gif"></img></span>
```

Comment: This fixes the issue but alignment on it is not great though.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to be able to change "Some Text" through jquery that's why I had this additional span.

Comment: if you dont want use additional span or other element,you can use display:inline style in previous element of icon img

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty `<span>` in there that is pushing the icon image down. This: `<span class"status"></span>` adds 5px to the top of the image. You could get rid of this empty tag altogether to make the image move up, or add this css to fix it:
`div.tableDiv div.statusLine span .status { padding: 0; display: inline;}`

Comment: Since I can't comment above, I have to here...
@GentlePurpleRain - my answer is correct. Take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/h94g8a3t/

Answer (score 0):

You have padding in your CSS that is moving the icons over, take that out.  For alignment add a `line-height` and `vertical-align` attribute.

```
div.tableDiv { display:table; }
div.tableDiv div.statusLine { display:table-row; }
div.tableDiv div.statusLine span { 
    display:table-cell; 
    line-height:16px;
    vertical-align:middle;
} 
img.icon {
   border-style: none;
}
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e1jbmbo5/1/)**

If you want to add some spacing between your text and icon you can do so by adding a `margin-left` to the `img.icon` CSS.